# Problema com tablayout e sqlite

Tags: sqlite, android-fragment

Olá pessoal estou reformulando um app e inclui na activity principal um tablayout que infla dois fragments. Um fragment deveria apresentar num cardview todos os dados armazenados no banco de dados. Rolando a tela para a esquerda o outro fragment deveria apresentar em outro cardview todos os itens especificados numa query diferente.

Acontece que se eu deixar o fragment dois vazio, o fragment 1 apresenta os dados corretamente, no entanto se programar o fragment 2 para apresentar os dados específicos o fragmente 1 passa a mostrar esses dados também.

No meu helper tenho duas querys diferentes para cada situação que chamo elas dentro de cada fragment.

**HELPER**

**QUERY 01**

```
/* Recupera todos dados do banco de dados*/
public ArrayList<Lista> getLista1(){
    ArrayList<Lista> listaArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM "+AssetHelper.TABLE_NAME;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do {
            Lista lista1 = new Lista();
            lista1.setSubcategoria(cursor.getString(0));
            lista1.setClassificacao(cursor.getString(1));               
            lista1.setDescricao(cursor.getString(2));                
            listaArrayList.add(lista1);
        }while(cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return listaArrayList;
}
```

**QUERY 2**

```
/* Recupera os dados específicos do banco de dados*/
public ArrayList<Lista> getLista2(){
    ArrayList<Lista> lista2ArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    String query2 = "SELECT * FROM "+AssetHelper.TABLE_NAME+" WHERE "+AssetHelper.COLUM_ESP+" = 1";
    SQLiteDatabase dbesp = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursoresp = dbesp.rawQuery(query2,null);

    if (cursoresp.moveToFirst()){
        do {
            Lista lista2 = new Lista();
            lista2.setSubcategoria(cursoresp.getString(0));
            lista2.setClassificacao(cursoresp.getString(1));               
            lista2.setDescricao(cursoresp.getString(2));                
            lista2ArrayList.add(lista2);
        }while(cursoresp.moveToNext());
    }
    return lista2ArrayList;
}
```

**ACTIVITY**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    //Fragments
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    addFragmentsToViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    //Fim fragments
}

private void addFragmentsToViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    TabsFragmentPagerAdapter adapter = new TabsFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new Lista01Fragment(), getString(R.string.lista_01));
    adapter.addFragment(new Lista02Fragment(), getString(R.string.lista_02));
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
}
```

**FRAGMENT 01**

```
public class Lista01Fragment extends Fragment {

    CidsAssetHelper helpher;
    List<Lista> lista;
    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

    public Lista01Fragment {
    }

    public static Lista01Fragment() newInstance() {
            Lista01Fragment() fragment = new Lista01Fragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setRetainInstance(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_lista_01, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

            helpher = new AssetHelper(getActivity());
            lista = new ArrayList<Lista>();
            lista = helpher.getLista1();

            mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_lista1);
            mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

            mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
            mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

            mAdapter = new Adapter(getActivity(),lista);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }
}
```

**FRAGMENT 2**

```
public class Lista02Fragment() extends Fragment {

AssetHelper helpher2;
List<Lista> list2;
RecyclerView mRecyclerView2;
private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter2;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager2;

public Lista02Fragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

public static Lista02Fragment() newInstance() {
    Lista02Fragment() fragment = new Lista02Fragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_lista_2, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);


    helpher2 = new AssetHelper(getActivity());
    lista2 = new ArrayList<Lista>();
    lista2 = helpher2.getLista2();

    mRecyclerView2 = (RecyclerView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_lista2);
    mRecyclerView2.setHasFixedSize(true);

    mLayoutManager2 = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    mRecyclerView2.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager2);

    mAdapter2 = new Adapter(getActivity(),lista2);
    mRecyclerView2.setAdapter(mAdapter2);

}
}
```

**ADAPTER**

```
public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.ViewHolder>  {

static   List<Lista> list;
static  Context context;

public Adapter(Context context, List<Lista> list){
    this.list = new ArrayList<Lista>();
    this.context = context;
    this.list = list;
}

@Override
public Adapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
            R.layout.lista, null);

    // create ViewHolder
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(itemLayoutView);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(Adapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.subactegoria.setText(cidsList.get(position).getSubcategoria());
    holder.descrabrev.setText(cidsList.get(position).getDescrabrev());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    public TextView subactegoria,descrabrev;

    public ViewHolder(View itemLayoutView) {
        super(itemLayoutView);
        subactegoria = (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.tv_subcategoria);
        descrabrev = (TextView)itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.tv_descriabreviada);
        itemLayoutView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context,DetalhesActivity.class);

        Bundle extras = new Bundle();
        extras.putInt("position",getAdapterPosition());
        intent.putExtras(extras);

        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
}
```

Gostaria de saber porque isso acontece?
Como fazer para que cada um dos fragments mostre os dados distintos entre eles?

Comment: Se o fragment 2 não estiver vazio, o app funciona corretamente?

Comment: @Rene Freak se eu executar o app do jeito que está sendo demonstrado acima o app executa e os cardviews dos dois fragments são preenchidos com os mesmos dados. Ou seja, ambos são preenchidos com os dados da query2. Se seu comentar o código do fragment dois o cardview do fragment 1 é preenchido corretamente com os dados da query 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode ser que, mesmo aparentando ser diferentes, os `selects` trazem o mesmo resultado. E portanto, são iguais.

Mas além disso, no query 2, tem alguns erros. Este trecho:

```
if (cursoresp.moveToFirst()){
    do {
        Lista lista2 = new Lista();
        lista2.setSubcategoria(cursor.getString(0));
        lista2.setClassificacao(cursor.getString(1));               
        lista2.setDescricao(cursor.getString(2));                
        lista2ArrayList.add(lista2);
    }while(cursoresp.moveToNext());
}
```

deveria ser:

```
   if (cursoresp.moveToFirst()){
        do {
            Lista lista2 = new Lista();
            lista2.setSubcategoria(cursoresp.getString(0));
            lista2.setClassificacao(cursoresp.getString(1));               
            lista2.setDescricao(cursoresp.getString(2));                
            lista2ArrayList.add(lista2);
        }while(cursoresp.moveToNext());
    }
```

Compare e veja as pequenas diferenças. No primeiro caso, você pega os dados do outro `cursor`. O segundo apresenta as correções.

Comment: o código acabou ficando diferente ao colá-lo aqui, mas no app estão corretos.

Comment: Vi que corrigiu na pergunta. Você verificou se ambas consultas estão retornando os mesmos valores? Você tentou depurar (debug) linha a linha pra ver quando os desvios ocorrem?

Comment: No debug o tamanho das listas fica diferente, esse é o objetivo, no entanto na activity com os dois fragments não mostra os resultados diferentes, ou seja no fragment 1 deve mostrar todos os dados, já no fragment 2 apenas um.

O fato de estarem utilizando um mesmo adapter influencia?

Comment: O único adapter que vi, que ambos fragments usam é do viewpager e ele está correto. Pelo que diz, parece que você depurou (debug) partes do código isoladas. O debug que falei, é com o app rodando. Colocando os breakpoints estrategicamente, vc vai perceber onde o app erra.