# Demora em carregar RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-adapter, android-recyclerview

É normal demorar 3 segundos para carregar um recyclerview com dados de 16 mil registros no sqlite?

Há alguma maneira de optimizar o carregamento?

[Código aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/198450/problema-com-tablayout-e-sqlite)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como o amigo acima citou e olhando o seu código, você não precisa fazer esse carregamento de toda a base de uma vez, só vai onerar performance e memória do aparelho.

RecyclerView foi feita justamente para trabalhar com quantidade de dados grandes justamente porque ele só carrega em memória os dados que estão visíveis na tela, enquanto o Adapter da mesma faz toda essa gestão durante um scroll de descartar os dados que saem da tela ou buscar novos dados da base quando aparecem na tela.

Para isso você tem que implementar um Content Provider no seu app para intermediar os acessos à base (e permitir buscar dados específicos que você mencionou num comentário acima) e implementar um CursorLoader na sua Activity para manter o RecyclerView automaticamente sempre atualizado quando a base for modificada.

Dá uma olhada nesse gratuito. Explica muito bem tudo que acabei de falar:

https://www.udacity.com/course/new-android-fundamentals--ud851

Comment: O que tem o Content Provider haver com performance?

Comment: O Content Provider não tem a ver com performance. Tem a ver com boas práticas de abstração da camada de dados e manutenção do código, além de trabalhar bem com Loaders.

Comment: Sim eu sei isso, mas você diz: *"Para isso você tem que implementar um Content Provider"*. O que eu quis dizer é que não é pelo facto de usar um Content Provider que vai resolver o problema de performance, o problema está na query.

Comment: Não entendi, qual o problema da query?

Comment: O problema do AP é "Demora em carregar RecyclerView" isso tem haver com o facto de ele estar a carregar(query) 16 mil registos de uma vez. O facto de passar a usar um Content Provider não irá resolver o problema se se continuar a carregar(query) 16 mil registos.

Comment: @ramaral a query dele não tem nenhum problema. O problema é como ele a está utilizando. Ele está carregando todos os 16 mil registros de uma vez num ArrayList e passando para o adapter da RecyclerView. Com o Content Provider implementado, ele poderia usar um CursorLoader (que passa uma URI para o ContentProvider, por isso ele é necessário) no lugar de um Loader comum, com isso, o adapter passaria a acessar um Cursor que vai retornar do BD apenas os dados referentes à posição da lista que está em exibição e não mais os 16 mil dados de uma vez. O CursorLoader também mantém o Recycler atualizado.

Comment: Isso que você diz é verdade e a solução passa por usar um Adapter que use um Cursor. O uso do Content Provider é opcional. Acho que implementar um  Content Provider apenas para preencher uma ListView é algo exagerado. Mas isso é uma questão de opinião.

Comment: Eu já penso o contrário, rs. Meu sentimento é que o ContentProvider / CursorLoader foi criado pensando em ListViews. Por exemplo, se a base do app for atualizada por um Service  em background, você não precisaria se preocupar com nenhuma implementação extra na UI se já possuir um CursorLoader para gerenciar a ListView.

Comment: Eu nunca disse que não há vantagens em usar Content Provider. Veja o que a [documantação](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html) diz: *(...)provedores de conteúdo se destinam principalmente ao uso por outros aplicativos, que acessam o provedor usando um objeto cliente do provedor.(...)*

Comment: Eu conheço a documentação. Estudei há pouco tempo. Só disse que era um sentimento meu.

Comment: Na verdade, estava me referindo ao CursorLoader (que exige um ContentProvider), por isso acabo tratando os 2 como uma coisa só como solução para trabalhar com ListViews. Essa resposta no SO em inglês dá uma boa explicação sobre os benefícios de um CursorLoader: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7182920/what-are-the-benefits-of-cursorloaders

Answer (score 1):

É normal sim. e nem precisam ser tantos registros. Boa parte deste tempo é a montagem do recurso na memoria do aparelho. As opções são:

1. Melhorar a query. Por que carregar 16 mil registros de uma vez?
2. Usar `content provider` e `loader` para cuidar do carregamento do `recycler view`... E melhorar a query.

[Fundamentos do ContentProvider](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html?hl=pt-br)

EDIÇÃO: em resposta a seus comentários, expando a resposta.

É preciso entender que a `filosofia` de um app móvel é diferente de de um sistema desktop. No desktop, pode até fazer sentido carregar uma grande quantidade de dados, mas no móvel, o usuário abre e fecha o app em segundos. Se seu app usa estes segundos pra carregar milhares de registros, antes de terminar a carga, o usuário já fechou.

Quanto a sua ideia de carregar uns poucos dados na lista, pode ser uma solução, mas vou te sugerir o modelo do Google.

Nenhuma informação a mostra até você começar a digitar, quando uma lista de sugestões aparece.

Você vai encontrar a resposta pro seu dilema combinando `content provider`, `loader` e `auto complete`

Comment: na verdade eu carrego os dados para depois o usuário pesquisar entre os códigos. Talvez não seria necessário carregar todos os dados de uma vez, conforme o usuário fosse rolando a tela esses dados poderiam ir sendo carregados, mas não sei como faz isso.

Já tentei modificar a query mas continuou demorando o carregamento.

Comment: O que tem o Content Provider haver com performance?

Comment: Tem a ver o que expliquei na minha resposta. Você consegue usar os benefícios de um CursorLoader para manter a gestão dos dados numa thread em background e não precisar ficar carregando a base toda em memória.

Comment: O que eu quero salientar é que *"não precisar ficar carregando a base toda em memória"* nada tem haver com usar Contente Provider ou não.

Comment: Não tem haver mesmo. Não carregar a base toda é simplesmente um "boa prática". O uso de content provider + loader é sugerido para cuidar do carregamento dos dados.